# How to save changes in Feature-Geometry with GDAL/OGR and Python? (Segmentation fault)

Tags: python, gdal, geometry

I have a problem with my code:

```
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
dataSource = driver.Open('merge.shp', 0)
if dataSource is None:
    print 'Could not open file'
    sys.exit(1)
layer = dataSource.GetLayer() #layer = Shapefile

numFeatures = layer.GetFeatureCount()
i = 0
intersec_count=0
while i < (numFeatures-2):
    feature1 = layer.GetFeature(i)
    geom1 = feature1.GetGeometryRef()
    j = i+1
    while j < numFeatures:
        feature2 = layer.GetFeature(j)
        geom2 = feature2.GetGeometryRef()   
           if geom1.Distance(geom2)<0.0001 and geom1.Distance(geom2)!=0:
              buff = geom1.Buffer(0.0001)
              linkline = geom2.Intersection(buff)
              linkpoint = linkline.GetPoint(0)
              geom1.AddPoint(linkpoint[0],linkpoint[1])
              feature1.SetGeometry(geom1)
        j = j+1
    i = i+1
dataSource.SyncToDisk()
dataSource = None
```

When running this script the folloging Message appears:
"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

All I'm trying to do, is to add a Point (linkpoint) to a LineString (geom1) and save these changes.

I hope someone can help me :)

Comment: I do not understand what you're trying to do

Comment: Segmentation fault is a memory error. How many records are in your shapefile?

Comment: Any chance your geometries contain 4d(XYZM) coordinates? I've seen a lot of segfaults due to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this, you need to create new ogr features and save them to the layer and not simply create geometries ( `geom1.AddPoint(linkpoint[0],linkpoint[1])`, `feature1.SetGeometry(geom1)`), with `dataSource.SyncToDisk()` at the end (SyncToDisk() might be helpful to ensure that a particular feature is flushed to disk but it is not necessary here, look at the script).

```
# open the shapefile specifying that the data can be updated
from osgeo import ogr
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
datasource = driver.Open('merge.shp', 1) # 1 -> the layer can be updated
layer = datasource.GetLayer()
featureDefn = layer.GetLayerDefn()
numFeatures = layer.GetFeatureCount()
i = 0
while i < (numFeatures-2):
    feature1 = layer.GetFeature(i)
    geom1 = feature1.GetGeometryRef()
    j = i+1
    while j < numFeatures:
         feature2 = layer.GetFeature(j)
         geom2 = feature2.GetGeometryRef()  
         if geom1.Distance(geom2)<0.0001 and geom1.Distance(geom2)!=0:
             buff = geom1.Buffer(0.0001)
             linkline = geom2.Intersection(buff)
             linkpoint = linkline.GetPoint(0)
             # create a new ogr geometry with wkt here
             wkt = 'POINT(%f %f)' % (linkpoint[0],linkpoint[1])
             point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)  
             # write the new feature  
             newFeature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)      
             newFeature.SetGeometryDirectly(point)
             layer.CreateFeature(newFeature)
             # here you can place layer.SyncToDisk() if you want
             newFeature.Destroy()
         j = j+1
    i = i+1
datasource.Destroy() # or datasource = None
```

But instead of using nested `while` loops use a `for` loop or better, the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) standard module.

```
import itertools
...
datasource = driver.Open('merge.shp', 1)
layer = datasource.GetLayer()
featureDefn = layer.GetLayerDefn()
for feature1,feature2 in  itertools.combinations(layer, 2):
     geom1 = feature1.GetGeometryRef()
     geom2 = feature2.GetGeometryRef()
     if geom1.Distance(geom2)<0.0001 and geom1.Distance(geom2)!=0:
         outFeature = ogr.Feature(featureDefn)
         buff = geom1.Buffer(0.0001)
         linkline = geom2.Intersection(buff)
         linkpoint = linkline.GetPoint(0)
         wkt = 'POINT(%f %f)' % (linkpoint[0],linkpoint[1])
         point = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(wkt)         
         outFeature.SetGeometryDirectly(point)
         layer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
         outFeature.Destroy()

datasource.Destroy()
```